# Normalize [database]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[database](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/database) is largely a meta tag.  Unlike the [spreadsheet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) tag, its definition doesn't cover a non-meta usage, although there is some non-meta usage among the questions.  It looks like the vast majority of usage is as an unnecessary, redundant tag when an application-specific tag is also used.  After some recent cleanup, there are probably 350 questions (out of about 400 remaining) for which the tag is unnecessary.

As far as the [database](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/database) tag, itself, it should be retained and the wiki excerpt modified to limit its application to specific non-meta uses.

Comment: I vote editing. Specifically expanding the wiki except, so that in addition to it's current definition of what a database is it describes what the tag is used for, database-software, and database related questions. You're quite the busy bee fixer1234 :).

Comment: @RobinHood - I'm getting that a lot from my wife. :-)  The thing is, there are already application-specific tags, so a generic definition would keep it a meta tag, which is undesirable.  If we keep the tag, it should be for questions that are either database-related but not restricted to a specific program, or about interoperability between programs, like the definition for the spreadsheet tag.  On both, it wouldn't hurt to add a push to an application-specific tag if appropriate.